# Exchange online account: Failed to find ASUrl and OABUrl in autodiscover response

Tags: 14.04, email, evolution, online-accounts, ms-exchange

I have configured an Exchange online account that was working flawlessly for the last months. It is a company account for Office 365 and I'm using https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx as host URL.

Last week it suddenly stopped working with this error message:

> The reported error was "Invalid password with username 'my.name@company.com' (goa-error-quark, 0): Failed to find ASUrl and OABUrl in autodiscover response".

The credentials are not wrong, they are the same I use on outlook.com and they worked till last week.

Comment: same problem here

Comment: @JanTobola you should upvote the question if you have the same problem. Commenting does not increase the visibility of the question. Voting does.